# SwiftUI: does modifier create a new view or return a modified view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm reading SwiftUI materials and it's said that view modifiers for example:

```swift
struct ByeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Bye bye, world!")
            .font(.headline)
    }
}
```

creates a new view with `.headline` font and returns the view.

So I wonder if it's more like:

```swift
func font(_ font: UIFont) -> Text {
    Text(text, font: font)
}
```

rather than:

```swift
func font(_ font: UIFont) -> Text {
    self.font = font
    return self
}
```

I feel for event modifiers, since they may not have to *modify* the view, there's no need to "create a new view with modified aspects", but not sure about the modifiers that do adjust the views.

Thanks!

Comment: This is intentionally hidden as an implementation detail. But note that `self.font = font` is impossible as none of the view modifiers are `mutating`, though `self.someReferenceType.font = font` *is* possible.

Comment: Oh that's right @Sweeper it's a `struct` so potentially Apple may not want you to actually _modify_ the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that an implementation such as

```
func font(_ font: UIFont) -> Text {
    self.font = font
    return self
}
```

does not compile. `font` would need to be `mutating` for this to work, but it isn't `mutating`. That said, this would have compiled:

```
self.someReferenceType.font = font
```

But this has another problem. This means that `font` now has a side effect:

```
var body: some View {
    let x = Text("foo")
    x.font(.headline)
    return x // this should have non-headline font, but if the 
             // implementation above were used, it would have headline font
}
```

So I think it is very likely that the actual implementation involves calling the initialiser, rather than `return self`. This also matches the wording in the documentation's wording that a "new view" is "created".

For modifiers that return `some View`, you can check the type they return using `type(of:)`. You will most likely see that the type they return is different from `self`, which means they definitely do not `return self`! After all, that's one of the reasons why the opaque type `some View` is used in the signature - to hide the internal types Apple used to implement these modifiers.

```
// doesn't work in a playground for some reason
// make a .swift file, compile and run
let x = Text("foo").onAppear {}
print(type(of: x))
```

For me, this prints: `ModifiedContent<Text, _AppearanceActionModifier>`, not `Text`, so clearly a new view is created here. (See also [`ModifiedContent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/modifiedcontent))

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR

We can't know for sure as the implementation detail is hidden.

##### My point of view

I might be wrong but I think it's possible that neither of modifying an instance of a View or assigning to a property that you have described are actually happening, but we can't know for sure since the implementation is private.

Since SwiftUI is a declarative framework, where you describe what you want to get and the OS takes care of that, it could be even that by writing:

```swift
SomeView()
    .padding()
    .background(Color.red)
    .cornerRadius(8)
```

Internally it could become just about any representation such as JSON that the parser could read.

Essentially no instance of any object (apart from the description) representing a View, Color or CornerRadius could exist before its initialization based on the description and current state, thus there would be no instance holding properties (such as font) that could be assigned or altered before the final View is initialized.